# How to map two One or Zero to One relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, mapping

I have three entities with the name of SellinRequest, MortgageAndRent and Album. Each of SellinRequest and MortgageAndRent may have an Album.

```
public class SellingRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }  
}

public class MortgageAndRent
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public Album Album { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SellingRequest SellingRequest { get; set; }
    public int SellingRequestId { get; set; }

    public MortgageAndRent MortgageAndRent { get; set; }
    public int MortgageAndRentId { get; set; }

    public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

This is the logic I want to be implemented:

- (SellingRequest 1 .... 0-1 Album)
- (MortgageAndRent 1 .... 0-1 Album)

With these mappings:

```
public class SellingRequestMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SellingRequest>
{
    public SellingRequestMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("SellingRequest");
        this.HasKey(sR => sR.Id);

        // Each SellingRequest may have one Album. (SellingRequest 1 .... 0-1 Album)
        this.HasOptional(sR => sR.Album).WithOptionalPrincipal(a => a.SellingRequest).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public RentAndMortgageMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("MortgageAndRent");
        this.HasKey(mR=>mR.Id);

        // Each MortgageAndRent may have one Album. (MortgageAndRent 1 .... 0-1 Album)
        this.HasOptional(sM => sM.Album).WithOptionalPrincipal(a => a.MortgageAndRent).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

But I couldn't get the result. I don't know how to relate these two tables to Album table!

Comment: Your Album entity does not have a Key defined. Also after "WithOptionalPrincipal" I would recommend "MapKey" to point to a foreign key.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by *But I couldn't get the result*.

Comment: @Milos Mijatovic Thank you very much for remembering me. In original code I have the Id but I forgot to write the Id here.

Comment: @MilosMijatovic Would you please explain a little more about this line: " After "WithOptionalPrincipal" I would recommend "MapKey" to point to a foreign key." – Atefeh Mohammadpoor

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it w/o the fleunt syntax.  Note the new *id* fields and that I marked the album properties as *virtual*

```
public class SellingRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AlbumId {get;set;}

    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }  
}

public class MortgageAndRent
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int AlbumId {get;set;}

    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SellingRequestId { get; set; }   
    public int MortgageAndRentId { get; set; }

    public virtual SellingRequest SellingRequest { get; set; }
    public virtual MortgageAndRent MortgageAndRent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello @jhilden. Thanks for your answer. I've changed the code the way you suggested with my own mapping (The mapping is considered above.). But I get this error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'RealEstateV1Database1.dbo.Album'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."} though I have put this line of code in Album Mapping: this.HasKey(a => a.Id);
            this.Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Comment: Would I please now your idea about mappings?